# How to write a value from the command line to a database if it's a certain double value

Tags: java, database, if-statement, integer, double

I'm working on a USB Scale program that reads value's from an external weighing scale and writes them to the command line when a weighted object is placed on it in an infinite loop. However what I am attempting to do is incorporate an else if statement that when the value is equal to the double value 'Dozen Eggs' of the weighted object it queries the database and inserts the values and attributes into the table. The integer doesn't seem to compare to the double value and skips over the if statement and therefore I was wondering how would I be able to make the else if statement recognizable and for it to write to the database in real time, simultaneously to when the values are writing to the command line?

I've tested the connection to the database in a separate class and it commits the attributes perfectly so the connection isn't the issue.

```
@Override
public void dataEventOccurred(UsbPipeDataEvent upde) {
    boolean empty = data[1] == 2;
    boolean overweight = data[1] == 6;
    boolean negative = data[1] == 5;
    boolean grams = data[2] == 2;
    int scalingFactor = data[3];
    double DozenEggs = 144.0;
    double OneEgg = 0.2;
    int AverageSellingUnitWeight = (data[4] & 0xFF) + (data[5] << 8);

    if (empty) {
        System.out.println("EMPTY");
    } else if (overweight) {
        System.out.println("OVERWEIGHT");
    } else if (negative) {
        System.out.println("NEGATIVE");
    } else if (AverageSellingUnitWeight == DozenEggs) {
        // then we have a dozen eggs in the fridge.
        // add 6 eggs to Fridge table in the database.

        try {
            // create a mysql database connection
            String myDriver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smartfridge?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false;";
            Class.forName(myDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "admin");

            // the mysql insert statement
            String query = " insert into fridge (name, UnitOfSale, ContentsQuantity, department, AverageSellingUnitWeight)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setString(1, "Eggs");
            preparedStmt.setInt(2, 1);
            preparedStmt.setInt(3, 6);
            preparedStmt.setString(4, "Milk, Butter & Eggs");
            preparedStmt.setDouble(5, DozenEggs);

            // execute the preparedstatement
            preparedStmt.execute();

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You have five placeholders in your query. They're numbered 1-5. You're using 2-6 in your code (ex.: `preparedStmt.setString(2, "Eggs");`). You should be using 1-5.

Comment: When asking for help, please use consistent and reasonably-standard indentation and bracing. (It's a good idea when not asking for help, too.)

Comment: You should not have any problems comparing integers and doubles. In this case the integer is first converted into double and they are compared after.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Fixed the indentation and placeholders. The problem still persists that when I put a weight of 144.0 g's on the scale it still doesn't go into the else if statement to write the attributes into the database.

Comment: @JoelC1310 - The indentation of the code in the question is still inconsistent and non-standard, the bracing is still...unconventional. (Why do you have a freestanding block within the block of your final `else if`?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry was rushing over it to get it formatted correctly. Should be okay now. Does that make the problem more clear?

Comment: The indentation was still all over the place. I gave up and fixed it for you and added a final `}` that I *assume* is in your actual code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay thank you, the reason why there isn't a final } in the statement is because I have another separate if statement that follows it which has a closing } but isn't relevant to my problem. Will you be able to help me on the main issue that I am having?

Comment: I'm afraid not. If `data[4]` contains 144 and `data[5]` contains 0, `AverageSellingUnitWeight` will be 144 and although it's not best practice, you can compare the `double` `DozenEggs` with the `int` `AverageSellingUnitWeight` successfully when the `double`'s value, truncated, equals the `int`'s value. So clearly, `data[4]` doesn't contain 144, and/or `data[5]` doesn't contain 0. Why that is isn't something we can help you with, you need to step through the code, examining the values, to see what's going on. I will note that if one egg is 0.2, then a dozen eggs would be 2.4, not 144.